# Remove windows border on chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

For some days I have the terrible windows border for my chrome apps, google note and google music.[image]

How can I remove this ugly thingy ?

Comment: Have you saw this one to let `margin` be `0`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681422/remove-fullscreen-window-decoration-border-chrome-os-app-kiosk-mode

Comment: Since this is the standard google chrome music app, I do not know where I should make these changes.

Comment: @DaytonWang, this has nothing to do with CSS; he's asking how to get rid of the Windows border and buttons.

Comment: @Pris0n, unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to do this right now. You can either run borderless full-screen, or in a window with browser-chrome.  Browsers don't currently let you run a borderless window ([Firefox no longer even allows removing the address bar](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1507375). ) Hopefully browser devs will eventually learn that webapps are the future and we'll *need* this functionality.