# how to resolve white bar at the bottom for chrome app in Kiosk mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

I published a private chrome app in the kiosk mode, it shows a white bar at the bottom of the screen. First time it displayed in the full screen but started to get issue once I rebooted the chrome box[image: White bar at the bottom]

Comment: Are there error logs that you can share the community? This seems like an unusual issue as I can't find any references about it on the documentation and [chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). If you want you can post this inquiry to them as well.

Comment: Is this a webview? Could be related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681422/remove-fullscreen-window-decoration-border-chrome-os-app-kiosk-mode